# Installing Jenkins on MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos, jenkins, osx-elcapitan

This is probably a stupid question but I can't get Jenkins installed on my MAC. I've searched the web and tried various different tutorials but it does not seem to work for me. Moreover it seems that nobody experiences the same problem. I've downloaded the **Jenkins Installer** from [here](https://jenkins.io/index.html). After running the installation process, the script tries to connect to `http://localhost:8080` but I get the error message that the browser *cannot connect to the server*. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And again the solution was quite simple. The connection problem arises when you either don't or you have **Java < 1.7** installed. What I did:

- deleted my previous Jenkins installation by running `/Library/Application\ Support/Jenkins/Uninstall.command`
- installed JDK 8 (OS X 64bit) from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
- reinstalled MAC Jenkins from [here](https://jenkins.io/index.html)

Works fine!

Comment: Direct link for avoid unnecessary download, install https://www.jenkins.io/download/lts/macos/